# Do I need to manually refresh banner ads using AdMob?

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, ionic3, cordova-admob

This is my first time using AdMob and I do not have this clear.

I successfully show a banner ad below my content but I am not sure if I need to refresh it every X time or it refreshes it self.

Anyone knows this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the banner should [refresh automatically optimized by Google](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3245199?hl=en).

You can customize it at the [AdMob Portal](https://www.google.com/admob/) in the Banner Advanced Settings.

I recommend you to keep this automatically.